# Centering new window in mainwindow

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog

This might be a duplicate but I Googled it and looked through StackOverFlow to try and find a fix for this problem and it still won't work.
I am trying to center a window (Input Dialog Box) in my main window.
It is supposed to be vertically centered and the the width of the new window (Dialog box) must be the width of the MainWindow.

This is what I tried so far:

```
Application curApp = Application.Current;
Window mainWindows = curApp.MainWindow;
this.Left = mainWindows.Left;
this.Top = mainWindows.Top + (mainWindows.ActualHeight - this.ActualHeight) / 2;
this.Width = mainWindows.ActualWidth;
```

The above code is located in the loaded event of the Dialog Window.

Although this centers it vertically, It doesn't place it in the exact center of the mainWindow (i.e. The Left properties don't match.)

Please help.

---

This is how I call the dialog box:

```
var dialog = new MyDialog();
dialog.ShowMessage("Capture Amount", "Please enter the 'Capture Amount'");
if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true) {
    DialogResponse = dialog.ResponseAmount.ToString();

    CustomTitleMain = "Main Window: " + CurrencyCode.ToString() + " " + DialogResponse.ToString();
}
```

DialogResponse, CurrencyCode and ResponseAmount are properties. First two are strings, last one is decimal.

Comment: You want something like
**mainWindows .WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;**

Comment: Does it make any difference if you set the `Width` property first?

Comment: No it doesn't, Its still off a bit.

Comment: @RohitPrakash I tried your approach and it didn't work.

Comment: Indeed i tried your code and it seems to work correctly. Can you post the more code? How do you open the DialogWindow?

Comment: Will add the code now. My code only works if the mainwindow in not maximized and is still in its manually set height and width. However I need it to work when the mainwindow is maximized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either set the StartupLocation of your Dialog in the Init like:

```
Application curApp = Application.Current;
Window mainWindows = curApp.MainWindow;
this.WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
this.Owner = mainWindows;
this.Left = mainWindows.Left;
this.Top = mainWindows.Top + (mainWindows.ActualHeight - this.ActualHeight) / 2;
this.Width = mainWindows.ActualWidth;
```

Or Set it when you are calling it:

```
var dialog = new MyDialog();
dialog.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
dialog.WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
dialog.ShowMessage("Capture Amount", "Please enter the 'Capture Amount'");
if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true) {
    DialogResponse = dialog.ResponseAmount.ToString();

    CustomTitleMain = "Main Window: " + CurrencyCode.ToString() + " " + DialogResponse.ToString();
}
```

But keep in mind that you could also set all these parameters via xaml. Which in my opinion makes it much more readable.

Comment: This helped me get to my answer and I will take your advice about doing this in xaml. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner` and also set the `Owner` property of the dialog window.

```
Window subWindow = new MyWindow();
subWindow.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
subWindow.WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
subwindow.ShowDialog();
```